# New build randomly 'freezes'

Tags: freeze

I have random freezes with my new build.  I can still use the mouse to move around, but clicking on some things (varies each time) will not perform the action.

When this happens, all the fan settings go to stock.  I can tell because I have led fans that are turned off via iCue and they come on when this happens.  Audio will continue to play and applications will continue to run for a bit until I click enough stuff and it locks up.  Power functions via windows no longer work, have to hard reboot.

I have tried memory checking, looking for corrupted files, etc., but with no luck.  It seems to occur at random and not necessarily under any sort of load as far as I can tell.  I appreciate any help!

Build
Case - Lian Li Dynamic 
Power - 750W EVGA G3 850 80+ Gold 
Mobo - MSI MPG B550 Gaming Plus
CPU - AMD Ryzen 7 5800X
Cooler - NZXT Kraken Z73
Memory - Corsair Vengeance RGB Pro 32 GB (2x16) 3200 CL16
SSDs - ADATA Ultimate SU800 1TB (this is the main HD)
- Samsung 970 Evo Plus 1TB
GPU - MSI Geforce RTX 2070 Gaming
Fans - 6 x Corsair LL120 w/ Node/USB hub
Peripherals - Anker 4xUSB hub, AmazonBasics Mic, Logi 615 Camera, Logi G502 Mouse, Logi G213 KB, Acer XF270HU Monitor, Samsung S24E650PL Monitor

Comment: Is the RAM on the mobo maker's compatibility list? Is the CPU or RAM overclocked? Any clues in the Event Log? Operating system fully updated and all correct drivers installed?

Comment: Do you see anything in event viewer in the system or application logs with a timestamp close to when you experience the issue?

Comment: have you tried unplugging as many of the fans as you can and see if the behavior changes? Between iCue instability and potential flutter with 6 fans kicking in at once, maybe there is a power problem (flutter; EMI; sag/brownout etc.) I dont think DC fans are a huge issue with EMI, but one never knows.